# How to prevent dpkg trigger cycle?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt-get, dpkg

I build a debian package which generates menu files using `update-menus`, but in many languages. It is activated via dpkg's trigger facility: "interest /usr/share/menu". Unfortunately provides the following output. It run well if I omit `update-menus`, however it lose its purpose in this case. How to write a script that gets activated as dpkg trigger and that calls `update-menus`?

```
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for icewm-menu-multilang-support ...
dpkg: cycle found while processing triggers:
 chain of packages whose triggers are or may be responsible:
  icewm-menu-multilang-support -> menu
 packages' pending triggers which are or may be unresolvable:
  icewm-menu-multilang-support: /usr/share/menu
  hicolor-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/hicolor
  desktop-file-utils: /usr/share/applications
  menu: /usr/share/menu
dpkg: error processing icewm-menu-multilang-support (--unpack):
 triggers looping, abandoned
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icewm-menu-multilang-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update-menus` will get called anyway, since `menu` registers the same interest you do. You just need to make sure your trigger runs first. Triggers obey dependency ordering, so an `Enhances: menu` on your package control file (or a Recommends: in the other direction) might do the trick.

Comment: my package's ```postinst trigger``` runs earlier than menu's one, even if ```Enhances: menu``` or ```Recommends: menu``` was declared in my package.

Comment: Then you're set? Run your generator stuff in your trigger, and don't run update-menus, the other trigger will do it.

Comment: uh sorry, I did not say, I call update-menus explicitely, because I want to generate system-wide menus like update-menus does - but in all of locales into separate directories for each locale. 
how to do the same as update-menus without triggering 'menu'?